# RegEx to transform a short date pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I need to transform (regex, preferably) a short date pattern string into a string of a different format.

For example, if I have `"dd/mm/yyyy"` in the end I want to see `"%d/%m/%y"`. Or if I have `"MMMM-DD-YY"`, I'd like to see `"%m-%d-%y"`. In other words, each part of the date format should be shortened to one character and prefixed with a percentage sign. The order of the parts and separators must stay the same.

Greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Wouldn't you lose valuable information in the process? Like, December (12) becomes January (1)? Please clarify.

Comment: @rmayer06, no, I am not talking about actual dates, just the short date format string. I need to know the positions of day, month, and year, but in a different form.

Comment: I don't see why you want to use a regex for this. [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) on `new[]{'/','-'}`, loop, take the first char, add a %... there's nothing tricky here. Where are you stuck?

Comment: A regex, if you really want... `(\w+)([/-])(\w+)\2(\w+)`. Pretty sure that will work. The `\2` ensures the 2nd separator matches the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
([\w])[\w]+([/-])([\w])[\w]+([/-])([\w])[\w]+
```

And replace with:

```
%$1$2%$3$4%$5
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/vJ7dL1

C#

```
string example1 = "dd/mm/yyyy";
string example2 = "MMMM-DD-YY";

Regex rgx = new Regex(@"([\w])[\w]+([/-])([\w])[\w]+([/-])([\w])[\w]+");

string result1 = rgx.Replace(example1, "%$1$2%$3$4%$5");
string result2 = rgx.Replace(example2, "%$1$2%$3$4%$5");

Console.WriteLine(result1);
Console.WriteLine(result2);
```

Output:

```
%d/%m/%y
%M-%D-%Y
```

Note: You could use `ToLower()` to ensure M-D-Y was lower case..  if you want.

Comment: That worked! Except I had to change `+` with `*` to cover such inputs as `"m/d/yyyy"`. Nevertheless, thanks so much!